# (Vetores VISUALG) -> Preciso armazenar os maiores valor de um vetor (podendo haver repetições) e após isso salvar a posição dos maiores

Tags: array, visualg, pseudocódigo

Crie um programa que leia a idade de 8 pessoas e guarde-as em um vetor. No
final, mostre:

a) Qual é a média de idade das pessoas cadastradas

b) Em quais posições temos pessoas com mais de 25 anos

c) Qual foi a maior idade digitada (podem haver repetições)

d) Em que posições digitamos a maior idade

Consegui fazer normalmente tudo, mas sem repetições. Ou seja, a partir da letra c) e d) creio que não esteja completo. Segue o código:

```
Algoritmo "81"
Var
 
   idade: vetor [1..8] de inteiro

   c, soma, maior, posi : inteiro

   media: real

Inicio
   
   maior<-0
   Para c <- 1 ate 8 faca
     
 Escreval ("Digite a idade da ", c, "º pessoa")
      
Leia (idade[c])
     
 soma<-soma+idade[c]
   Fimpara
   Para c <- 1 ate 8 faca
     
 Se idade[c] > 25 entao
         
Escreval ("Pessoa com mais de 25 anos na posição: ", c)
     
 Fimse
  
 Fimpara
   Para c <- 1 ate 8 faca
   
 Se idade[c] > maior entao
          
  maior]<-idade[c]
         
   posi <- c
        
 Fimse
  
 Fimpara

   Escreval ("A maior idade digitada foi ", maior)

   Escreval ("A posição da maior idade foi: ", posi)

   media <- soma / c

   Escreval ("A media de idades é: ", media)

Fimalgoritmo
```

Não estou conseguindo entender o funcionamento da letra c) e d) utilizando vetores. Como puderam ver, fiz somente com variáveis comuns e realmente travei nisso, não consigo resolver. Já tentei de várias formas com vetores mas não salvei, não sei se "maior" precisa ser um vetor, já tentei dessa forma mas a condição "Se idade[c] > maior[c]" não é válida. Enfim, realmente tô travado nisso.

Comment: É fora de escopo mas uma coisa que está incomodando sobre o ensino de algoritmos com visual g, você sabe o que são ou seu professor de algoritmos já ensinou a técnica de refinamentos sucessivos?

Comment: Não sei. Talvez eu já tenha tido contato com a técnica mas com o termo não. Estou aprendendo algoritmos sozinho e estava indo tudo muito bem até chegar nesse exercício.

Comment: Certeza que não teve contato, dá para notar pelo código. De coração , não use o visual g para escrever os algoritmos. Algoritmos devem ser feitos com caneta , papel e régua. Use o visual g apenas para corrigir o resultado final

Comment: Eu entendi o que quis dizer com a estrutura do código, estou estudando por tópicos e não quis aplicar procedimentos e funções nas atividades pra poder ir dominando cada coisa de forma independente e depois poder tomar liberdade pra utilizar essas chamadas. Enfim, agradeço as dicas

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver, foi só um nó na minha cabeça que tive por um tempo. Precisei somente percorrer o vetor com um "para" normalmente e criar um if que comparasse o vetor com a varíavel maior (=).

```
Var
   // Seção de Declarações das variáveis
   idade: vetor [1..8] de inteiro
   c, soma, maior, posi : inteiro
   media: real

Inicio
   // Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc...
   maior<-0

   Para c <- 1 ate 8 faca
      Escreval ("Digite a idade da ", c, "º pessoa")
      Leia (idade[c])
      soma<-soma+idade[c]

   Fimpara

   Para c <- 1 ate 8 faca

      Se idade[c] > 25 entao
         Escreval ("Pessoa com mais de 25 anos na posição: ", c)
      Fimse
   Fimpara

   Para c <- 1 ate 8 faca
    Se idade[c] > maior entao
            maior<-idade[c]

         Fimse
   Fimpara



   Escreval ("A maior idade digitada foi ", maior)

   media <- soma / c
   Escreval ("A media de idades é: ", media)
   
    Para c <- 1 ate 8 faca
       Se idade[c] = maior entao
          Escreval ("Maior valor na posição: ", c)

       Fimse
Fimpara
Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).